# Neo4j - query result wrong number of lines

Tags: neo4j

I don't understand the result I'm getting from Neo4j; The following line appears twice in the [neo4j console](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=6n6zbl):

```
(7 {ticket:71904579})   (3 {familly:"familly_2"})
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've got a duplicate edge. Since there are two edges that match your Cypher query, it makes sense that it would return both of them.

Comment: @user2562019 happens to the best of us, don't worry about it.